# How to open cmd when exec jar file (qt QProcess)

Tags: java, c++, qt, cmd, qprocess

I use Windows. I want to use QProcess in a running jar app (java/javaw). After starting that, open the cmd to show me information about working my jar app.

My problem is: when I exec my qt code, the Java app starts (in the background), but cmd doesn't open with the Java runtime.

My code:

```
QProcess process;
process.setWorkingDirectory("D:\\Programs\\Qt\\Units\\MyJavaProjects\\StackExp\\target");
process.setProgram("java.exe");
process.setArguments({"-jar","StackExp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"});
process.start();
process.waitForFinished (-1);

if (!process.waitForStarted())
{
    qDebug() << "1: " +process.readAllStandardOutput();
    qDebug() << "2: " +process.readAllStandardError();
    qDebug() << "The process didnt start" << process.error();
}
```

My jar app built in maven and it has type: Java Application.

I use `java.exe` and `javaw.exe`, both runtimes don't open cmd.

How can I exec jar app with QProcess or otherwise, and at the same time open cmd for see information about working jar app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `system()` command to run visible command prompt window. Replace you code with a oneliner:

```
system(QString("java.exe -jar D:\\Programs\\Qt\\Units\\MyJavaProjects\\StackExp\\target\\StackExp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar").toStdString().c_str());
```

If you see just a flashing of the window you can add timeout call after your java call as follows to figure out what went wrong with the java call:

```
system(QString("java.exe -jar D:\\Programs\\Qt\\Units\\MyJavaProjects\\StackExp\\target\\StackExp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar & TIMEOUT 5").toStdString().c_str());
```

Note that `system()` call blocks until it returns.

If you want to keep the handle to the process you need to use `QProcess`. You can run command prompt as follows but you don't see it as a separate console window but it runs in the background. You can see it in task manager as command prompt process though.

```
QProcess process;
process.setWorkingDirectory("D:\\Programs\\Qt\\Units\\MyJavaProjects\\StackExp\\target");
process.setProgram("cmd.exe");
process.setArguments({"/c", "java.exe -jar StackExp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"});
process.start();
process.waitForFinished();
qDebug() << "1: " +process.readAllStandardOutput();
qDebug() << "2: " +process.readAllStandardError();
```

**Update:**

It seems you can spawn a foreground console window by setting custom flags to the process with [QProcess::setCreateProcessArgumentModifier](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#CreateProcessArgumentModifier-typedef) as follows:

```
process.setCreateProcessArgumentsModifier(
            [](QProcess::CreateProcessArguments *args) {
    args->flags |= CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE;
    args->startupInfo->dwFlags &=~ STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
});
```

Tested with `ping` command:

```
#include <windows.h>


QProcess process;
process.setProgram("cmd.exe");
process.setArguments({"/c", "ping 127.0.0.1"});
process.setCreateProcessArgumentsModifier(
            [](QProcess::CreateProcessArguments *args) {
    args->flags |= CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE;
    args->startupInfo->dwFlags &=~ STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
});
process.start();
process.waitForFinished();
```

Comment: I use this code (Testedd with ping command) and have errors:
1) mainwindow.cpp:191: error: C2065: 'CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE': undeclared identifier
2) mainwindow.cpp:192: error: C2027: use of undefined type '_STARTUPINFOW'
3) mainwindow.cpp:192: error: C2227: left of '->dwFlags' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
4) mainwindow.cpp:192: error: C2065: 'STARTF_USESTDHANDLES': undeclared identifier

Comment: What do you think about it?

Comment: You are missing include. Add #include <windows.h>